# How to cache dependencies when using git pull in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, ssh, sha1, sha

Say we have this in a docker image:

```
RUN git clone <url>
RUN git pull
RUN npm install
```

we need the git pull to always run. But if package.json doesn't change, we don't need to re-install.

I have two questions - how can we get the git pull to always run? I believe we can cache bust using a `--build-arg`

However, if git pull always runs, then according to docker, so will the `npm install` command.

One thing we could do is use some custom logic to compare the sha-sum of the package.json files.

```
RUN git clone <url>
RUN git pull
ENV package_shasum $(sha1sum package.json)
RUN compare-shasums && npm install
```

does anybody know how to do this with Docker?
The reason why we are doing the git stuff in Docker instead of outside the container and copying files into the container is for making Jenkins easier to work with.

Comment: I don't believe you can have your `git pull` step always run, unless you are using some build arg on it or on a step before it. When it runs, subsequent steps will run as well. In my opinion this approach causes more problems than it solves. We are working with Jenkins and building things happily "the usual way" - build a new image on each git push or other appropriate logic.

Comment: Git push triggers a jenkins build, and the docker image build will pull the new code, doesn't seem to make a difference. Putting it inside the image/container means less jenkins config and that we can run it locally and it's the same as running on jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

Normally if we COPY code from the host to image, we can use this trick to cache dependencies:

```
COPY package.json .
RUN npm install
COPY . .
```

and that will only run `npm install` if the package.json file has changed.
But if we do the git pull in the Dockerfile, then it's a bit different, but we can do this:

```
RUN git clone git@github.com:ORESoftware/live-mutex.git
ADD https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ORESoftware/live-mutex/master/package.json package.json
RUN npm install
RUN git fetch origin/master
RUN git checkout master
```

and for bitbucket, the url would be:

```
https://bitbucket.org/<account>/<repo-name>/raw/<commit-sha-or-HEAD>/<filename>
```